# Converting String with toCharArray results in different Characters

Tags: android, string, arrays

This is baffling me. I am grabbing a `String` and converting it to a `Char array` but the resulting characters are not the same as the original `String`. What gives? I've tried it one character at a time as well as trying `toCharArray()`. Same results.

Output:

```
07-21 09:58:27.700: V/meh(22907): Loaded String = [C@42126d88

07-21 09:58:27.700: V/meh(22907): Convert to Char = [C@41693070
```

```
String temp = prefManager_.getString("PrevGameState", "");
Log.v("meh", "Loaded String = " + temp);

pieceStates_ = temp.toCharArray();
Log.v("meh", "Convert to Char = " + pieceStates_.toString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

System.out.println("Convert to Char = " + **String.valueOf(pieceStates_)** );

```
String.valueOf(Character_Array)
```

Above method converts it back to String object.

Comment: Apparently String.valueOf is the way to go and charArray.toString is useless. This solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: it's not useless, you were just trying to use for something that it doesn't work for =).

Comment: What does it do if not convert the character array to a string?

Answer (score 4):

The value it outputs is not a string indeed, it's a pointer in memory. Probably you are not overriding the `toString()` method or there is something wrong.

The fact that the two pointers are not the same doesn't mean that the two strings are not equal (which should be compared with `.equals(..)` and not in any different way).

To be more precise, if `pieceStates_.toString()` prints `[C@41693070` then the `toString` is not overridden and Java doesn't know how to print it. Same thing applies to the other variable. Then an array type in Java is not printable by default, you should use `Arrays.toString(..)` to actually see its content.

Comment: 07-21 10:41:17.997: V/meh(23890): .equals = false

Log.v("meh", ".equals = " + pieceStates_.toString().equals(temp));

Comment: Of course they are not equal: in Java a `char[]` is NOT equal to a `String`  containing the same characters and I don't see why it should. You are comparing radical different objects.

Comment: Log.v("meh", ".equals = " + pieceStates_.toString().equals(temp));

Comment: I converted to string before using the .equals function as you recommended. It is false. So no, I am not comparing char [] to String.

Comment: As I stated: you are converting a `char[]` array with an implicit conversion which is NOT meant to generate the string defined by the char array but a printable representation of the array (and of arrays in general). `toString` is NOT meant to be used on a char[].